# SharePoint 2010 Designer Set content approval status to Rejected breaks workflow

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a list which requires item approval.
In certain conditions the approval status must be set to Rejected without user intervention.

I built a workflow in SharePoint Designer 2010 where I perform the following when condtion is met

"then Set content approval status to Rejected with Current Item: Reject Reason"

This line of code is not executed. In fact the entire if statement in which this line of code resides does not execute.

Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: You should provide more detail. How can anyone help, when you don't show the *whole* workflow?

Comment: @OndrejTucny Regardless of the content of the workflow. It does not execute the Set content approval status.... eg.

Comment: @OndrejTucny Regardless of the content of the workflow. It does not execute the Set content approval status.... eg of workflow not working....

If Current Item:Status equals Assigned to Official
 If Current Item:Acceptance equals Accept
    Email Current Item:Created By
    then Set Status to Manager
 Else if Current Item: Acceptance equals Reject
    Email Current Item:Created By
    then Set Status to Manager
    then Set content approval status to Rejected with Current Item: Reject Reason